# Join and count in DQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony, dql

I have a MySQL command and I cannot find the equivalent in DQL. I am trying to fetch the list most commented posts. Here is the MySQL command :

```
SELECT posts.id, COUNT(comments.id) AS num
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON ( posts.id = comments.post_id )
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Here is the result :

```
id  num
1   8
2   9
3   17
4   7
5   6
6   20
7   7
8   10
9   14
10  7
```

In DQL, it should be :

```
SELECT post, COUNT(comment.id) AS num
FROM Entity\Post post
LEFT JOIN post.comments comment
GROUP BY post.id
```

But this gives :

```
id  num
1   50
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
```

I don't understand where the 50 comes from and why there is a difference between the 2 results. Could you tell me how to make this join work in Doctrine ?

Comment: What's the exact query generated by Doctrine? You can easily check it using Symfony's WDT. Also you should store total number of comments in `Post` table and in/decrement it whenever you add/remove a comment.

Comment: Hi Crozin, it is what I am doing actually. But I want to make this work because I want to add a statement like `WHERE post.date > ?` to get the "hotest" posts for last 24h, last day, last month... I am running these commands with `app/console doctrine:query:dql` and `app/console doctrine:query:sql`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've made a few test and I found that everything seems to be fine.

```
Video: id, title, ...
Comment: id, video_id, content, ...
```

Database schema is very simple and I think there's no need for any explanation.

```
#DQL:
    SELECT v.id, COUNT(c.id) AS num
    FROM Video v
    JOIN v.comments c
    GROUP BY v.id
    ORDER BY num DESC

#Generated SQL:
    SELECT v0_.id AS id0, COUNT(v1_.id) AS sclr1 
    FROM video v0_ 
    INNER JOIN video_comment v1_ ON v0_.id = v1_.video_id 
    GROUP BY v0_.id 
    ORDER BY sclr1 DESC

#Result set:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 148
                [num] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 96
                [num] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 111
                [num] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 139
                [num] => 1
            )

    )
```

If you select entire `Video` object instead of its id (`v` instead of `v.id` in `SELECT` clause) the query will execute as well. Of course instead of `id` element there will be an `Video` object under 0<sup>th</sup> element.

*Tested on Doctrine 2.1.0-DEV*

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**: People - This answer does **not** work. At least you can eliminate this from possible solutions.

```
SELECT post, COUNT(comment.id) AS num
FROM Entity\Post post
LEFT JOIN post.comments comment
GROUP BY post
```

You were grouping by `post.id`, not `post`

btw, this is a total guess. I don't know DQL, but I do know hibernate, and it seems similar-ish. If it's wrong I'll delete this answer - let me know by comment.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, grouping by `post` does not make any better. I have the exact same output.