# Doctrine 2: Subquery alias creates an extra level in results

Tags: doctrine-orm

Consider the following DQL:

```
SELECT
  a,
  (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Comment c WHERE c.article_id = a.id) num_comments
FROM Article a
```

I expect the result to contain all article columns plus the num_comments on the same level, but instead article columns are wrapped in an array at index 0:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    0 => array(
      "id" => 1,
      "title" => "Title",
    ),
    "num_comments" => 15
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => array(
      "id" => 2,
      "title" => "Title",
    ),
    "num_comments" => 20
  )
);
```

How do I keep all Article columns and any extra fields on the same level?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326284/join-and-count-in-dql should give you an answer.

SELECT a, COUNT(c.id) AS num_comments
    FROM Article a
    JOIN a.comments c
    GROUP BY a.id

Comment: @HariKT But then I can't get articles that have no comments.

If I use "SELECT a.id", everything works fine, so I know that it's not an SQL problem. Doctrine hydrates my results incorrectly when I fetch all Article columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll split my answer in short and long explanation (and alternate answers).

**Short explanation:**

```
SELECT a.field1
     , ...
     , a.fieldN
     , (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Comment c WHERE c.article_id = a.id) num_comments 
  FROM Article a
```

Then hydrate as ARRAY and it will return what you're expecting.

**Long explanation:**

Whenever you refer to an entity itself (in your case, "SELECT a"), this means you ARE requesting to return the entire entity isolated from any other element.
Doctrine by default always assign this entity to index 0 and goes on depending on how many FROM entities you're selecting. To change this behavior, all you have to do is alias the entity, just like you did with the sub-query:

```
SELECT a AS article
     , (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Comment c WHERE c.article_id = a.id) AS num_comments 
  FROM Article a
```

This would return to something like:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    "article" => array(
      "id" => 1,
      "title" => "Title",
    ),
    "num_comments" => 15
  ),
  1 => array(
    "article" => array(
      "id" => 2,
      "title" => "Title",
    ),
    "num_comments" => 20
  )
);
```

If you are looking to not return the entire entity, you can use the PARTIAL support and only return the fields you're interested in. Let's support you only want id (mandatory, because it's the entity identifier) and title:

```
SELECT PARTIAL a.{id, title} AS article
     , (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Comment c WHERE c.article_id = a.id) AS num_comments 
  FROM Article a
```

Another approach would be encapsulating the result into a DTO. This would provide more OO control when you decide to hydrate values as object. DQL would look like this:

```
SELECT NEW ArticleDTO(a, COUNT(c.id)) 
  FROM Article a
  LEFT JOIN a.comments c
 GROUP BY a.id
```

The reason why you cannot place the entire sub-query as an argument is due to a limitation on DQL. None ever requested a full sub-query, so for now we follows what JPA suggests which is a ScalarExpression.

Cheers,

Guilherme Blanco

Comment: Can we not have the following notation in DQL: "AS a.num_comments" so that the scalar could be on the same level as other Article columns in the resulting array? If this bears more discussion, I will open a ticket instead.

Answer (score 0):

What @hari mentioned is very close to the answer.

You just need to do a LEFT JOIN so you would get all the articles, even if they have no comments.

```
 SELECT a, COUNT(c.id) AS num_comments FROM Article a LEFT JOIN a.comments c GROUP BY a.id
```

and to have the COUNT in the same array as the article, I would say SELECT by the fields individually.

```
SELECT a.id, a.text, a.date, COUNT(c.id) AS num_comments FROM Article a LEFT JOIN a.comments c GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: This would limit me to only one aggregate function. It's a good workaround, but I like my queries to scale since I always add new features that require additional data.